# No package installer with python 3.3?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I just downloaded installed python 3.3 for Mac OS. I used the [standard package from python.org](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/python-3.3.0-macosx10.6.dmg)

I found no package installing tool in python 3.3. No pip, easy_install, setuptools.
Looks like a boot strap problem: how can I install a package-installing-package without a package-installing-package?

I'm I missing something obvious? Or do I need to take further steps in order to have a package installer?

Comment: @G.Kayaalp: This link to setuptools has no support for python 3.x, only 2.x eggs.

Comment: Download and run `distribute_setup.py`. See the instructions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

Comment: OK, so it's:
`1. curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
2. python3.3 distribute_setup.py
3. easy_install pip`
now I can use pip which is the modern recommended package installer.
@ThomasK, if you post this as an answer I will accept it, Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasK: please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) supplies an installer script, `distribute_setup.py`. So, on Unix-y systems with curl, you can use the following commands:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python3.3 distribute_setup.py
easy_install pip    # easy_install is part of distribute
```

If you don't have curl, download the script another way and run the other two commands.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasK. Python prides itself on being "batteries included". Lack of package installer is one big battery missing.

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance: Well, packaging on Python is still something of a mess. There's work being done to improve it, but it wasn't ready in time for 3.3.