# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' in Python 3.7 on Mac

Tags: python-3.7

I have python 3.7.2. I am trying to import numpy and keep getting this error. I use the terminal on Mac OS Mojave V 10.14.2

```
import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615005/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-3-3-5-on-mac-osx-10-9).
numpy is not part of the python standard library and needs to be installed separately.
There are instructions for mac install in the question I linked for you.